# 1.13.24_Guidance on Design block

Tags: fonts

Im helping someone to design a thumbnail for a youtube video.

So far the layout has been established and i had a placeholder for text on the top left
What Im going for is big med small w the fonts, but since I want to make sure the illustration is most dominant, I decided to make the biggest font at the bot, and then med and the smallest onces was supposed to be onthe top left.

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/LhQPSLJ/2024-01-13-09h45-53.jpg

However, once I started to try fonts to replace the gold lines, it just.... doesn't work.
None of the fonts look right or seem to fit and I am very stuck.
Would very much appreciate guidance and thoughts on where to go or how you would go about solving this problem.

Comment: That poor woman with overly sized breasts

Comment: Hi.  What does "big med small w the fonts" and "at the bot, and then med and the smallest onces" mean?  I'm really sorry but I can't actually understand much of your question.   Can you edit it please, and use standard English.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The floating stones and the rectangular frame must somehow be well ordered with the text. The current stone constellation doesn't allow as long text as you seem to want. If you need longer or bigger text make some room by moving a couple of stones.

The next example uses a font which might be drawn by hand and fits into the available space.

[image]

Does its text content support the goal of your work? Maybe, but that's only an opinion based on guesses with no actual knowledge, so ignore it.

Here's another example with more text:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot Aimo, I actually think your type feels pretty good,
I think my dilemna from the start has been probabyl trying to maintain the compositional value that the bold line placeholders were creating.

They were just a placehold but then they become part of the composition rather than a replcaable thing and now its like when zooming out to see the thunbnail as a whole, something is lost when the font is inserted Almost like the font cant replicate the feel or something i can put into words.